# react native change webview source on button click

Tags: react-native

I merely want to change the source of a webview component to a different url once a button outside of the webview is clicked. I'm blown away there is not an easier way to do this. I've been told to use 'refs' but I'm not even sure that will work considering my unique situation.

To convey what I'm looking to to I'm mixing in some web js.

```
doAppNotification() {
    // some objc code is run
    // receiveAppNotification is called
}

receiveAppNotification() {
    let wv = document.getElementById("webview"); // !! how can I do something like this in react native??
    wv.source="http://some.other.site";
}

...

<Webview 
  id="webview"
  source={{uri: "https://www.google.com"}} 
/>
<Button
  onClick={doAppNotification}
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use component state to achieve desired behavior. Changing state will fire a component re-render and will open up the new `uri` you set.

```
export default MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      url: 'https://defaulturl'
    }
  }

  someEvent = (e) => {
    this.setState({ url: 'https://toanewurl' });
  }

  render(){
    const { url } = this.state;
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <WebView source={{uri: url}} />
        <Button onClick={this.someEvent} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! I'm changing state after I receive a callback from an iOS library and in the new scope the `this` keyword is bound to a `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope` instead of `App`. What I did to bypass this is store a reference to `App` from the constructor by using a global variable. I'll have to research a better fix later.